# How can I trigger code if a user removed strikethrough formatting from a cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a Google Spreadsheet, and many cells have strikethrough text.

If a user removes the strikethrough formatting, I want it to send an email to someone to notify that the strikethrough formatting was removed.

If a user applies strikethrough formatting to a cell, this is able to trigger an On Change trigger, but it does not trigger On Edit. I have tried using On Change, and I can see that the change type is "FORMAT", but it does not tell me what type of formatting change was applied.

I would like to be able to tell if the user added strikethrough formatting, removed strikethrough formatting, etc. However, I am only able to assess the current state of the cell, and I'm not able to compare it to a previous state.

The sheet contains sensitive data and is controlled, so I can't maintain a separate copy of the sheet to make comparisons.

How is it be possible to tell if a user removed strikethrough on a cell and then send an email?

Comment: Can you share with us your sample code (with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) so that we can further help you.

Answer (score 2):

I used an installable onChange event and the PropertiesService to store all of the `line-throughs` on a page that triggered the onChange type of FORMAT.  If you have more that one sheet you will probably have to modify the code.  This is not meant to be a final solution.  Instead it's provided as a stepping stone to the final solution which you must complete for yourself.

```
function onMyChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType == "FORMAT") {
    let oflA = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('line-through'));
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    let flA = sh.getDataRange().getFontLines().map((r, i) => {
      let row = [];
      r.map((c, j) => {
        if (c == "line-through") {
          row.push(`${sh.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).getA1Notation()}`);
        } else {
          row.push(null);
        }
      });
      return row;
    }).flat().filter(e => e);
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('line-through',JSON.stringify(flA));
    let m = oflA.filter(e => !~flA.indexOf(e) ).flat();
    if(m.length > 0) { 
      //This is where you send an email
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<textarea cols="40" rows="12">Missing: ${JSON.stringify(m)}</textarea>`).setWidth(1200), "Debug");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate this solution, but it seems like this is a work-around to lack of functionality in Sheets. There is no way to easily reference the previous state of the cell in any way? Thank you for the innovative solution. I will try to implement it, because I can not think of a better way to do this currently. I will try locking the sheet that saves the properties for the text formatting, and hopefully this will work out. Thanks again.

Comment: It is definitely a workaround. And there is no other way that I know how to do it.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification :)